# How to save All models from h2o automl

Tags: r, h2o

I'm trying to save **all** the models from an `h2o.automl` as part of the `h2o` package. Currently I am able to save a single model using `h2o.saveModel(aml@leader, path = "/home/data/user")`.

How can I save **all** the models?

Here is my attempt on a sample dataset:

```
 library(h2o)
 h2o.init()
 prostate.hex <- h2o.importFile(path = paste("https://raw.github.com",
    "h2oai/h2o-2/master/smalldata/logreg/prostate.csv", sep = "/"),
    destination_frame = "prostate.hex")
```

Get data from github or import via `readr`:

```
 library(readr)
 prostate <- read_csv("/home/data/user/prostate.csv")

 prostate.hex<- as.h2o(prostate, "prostate.hex")

 aml <- h2o.automl(y = "CAPSULE", x = c("AGE","RACE","PSA","DCAPS"),
    training_frame = prostate.hex,
    max_runtime_secs = 180,
    exclude_algos = c("StackedEnsemble")
    )
```

Now I'm trying to save the models within `aml`:

```
mod_ids <- as_tibble(aml@leaderboard$model_id)
```

Now I can't figure out how to save the models:

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(mod_ids)) {
   print(mod_ids[i,])
   #h2o.saveModel(object = aml@leaderboard[[i]], "/home/data/user/")
 }
```

Here is what I've tried:

[tutorial automl](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/h2o-world-2017/automl/R/automl_binary_classification_product_backorders.Rmd#ensemble-exploration)

[H2O AUTOML: How to save reuse and build on top of existing automl models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349510/h2o-automl-how-to-save-reuse-and-build-on-top-of-existing-automl-models)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, it'll do your job:

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(mod_ids)) {

    aml1 <- h2o.getModel(aml@leaderboard[i, 1]) # get model object in environment
    h2o.saveModel(object = aml1, "C:/Users/sm/Documents/stack/models") # pass that model object to h2o.saveModel as an argument

  }
```